# Splitting objects inside Java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

I am wondering if it is possible to split an object inside a Stream. For example, for this `Employee`:

```
public class Employee {

    String name;
    int age;
    double salary;

    public Employee(String name, int age, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }

    public double getSalary() { return salary; }
}
```

I would like to perform some operation in the stream. For simplicity, let it be something like this (assume my code architecture does not allow to put this inside Employee class - otherwise it would be too easy):

```
public void someOperationWithEmployee(String name, int age, double salary) {
    System.out.format("%s %d %.0f\n", name, age, salary);
}
```

Now it looks like this:

```
Stream.of(new Employee("Adam", 38, 3000), new Employee("John", 19, 2000))
        // some conversations go here ...
        .forEach(e -> someOperationWithEmployee(e.getName, e.getAge(), e.getSalary));
```

The question is, is it possible to put some code inside a stream like this?

```
Stream.of(new Employee("Adam", 38, 3000), new Employee("John", 19, 2000))
        // some conversations go here
        .forEach((a, b, c) -> someOperationWithEmployee(a, b, c));
```

What am I trying to achieve? - I think if I could map some object fields and then process them like `.forEach(this::someOperationWithEmployee)` code readability would be improved slightly.

---

**Update 14.05.2015**

Without a doubt to pass an `Employee` object to `someOperationWithEmployee` is prettiest solution in this case but sometimes we can not do this in real life and should be universal solution with lambdas.

Comment: It will be more of a trouble I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this fit your needs but it works with a bit of refection and not checking some types.

You can run my solution this way:

```
    Stream.of(new Employee("Adam", 38, 3000), new Employee("John", 19, 2000))
        .forEach(
                e->ArrayCaller.<TriConsumer<String, Integer, Double>>convert(e::getName, e::getAge, e::getSalary)
                                                                     .call((a, b, c) -> operation(a, b, c)));
```

It would call this simple method of the 'main' class:

```
private void operation(String name, int age, double salary) {
    System.out.format("%s %d %.0f\n", name, age, salary);
}
```

Of course it needs this auxiliary types:

```
/** Extending interfaces must have a method called consume with N args */
interface NConsumer {}

/*
 * Method must be called consume for reflection.
 *
 * You can define N interfaces like this.
 */
nterface TriConsumer<A, B, C> extends NConsumer {
    void consume(A a, B b, C c);
}

interface ArrayCaller<E extends NConsumer> {
    void call(E code);
    static <T extends NConsumer> ArrayCaller<T> convert(Supplier<?>...argSuppliers) {
        final Object[] args = new Object[argSuppliers.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < argSuppliers.length; i++) {
            args[i] = argSuppliers[i].get();
        }
        return new ArrayCaller<T>() {
            @Override
            public void call(T code) {
                for (Method m: code.getClass().getMethods()) {
                    if (m.getName().equals("consume")) {
                        try {
                            m.invoke(code, args);
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException
                                | IllegalArgumentException
                                | InvocationTargetException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's still better to define separate methods for 1, 2, 3, etc. arguments up to some reasonable limit, so you will have compile-time type checking and don't have to cast explicitly. Also it will work significantly faster.

Comment: Right, I thought about `call` methods for predefined XCosumer interfaces but one for NConsumer to call any other number of args with user defined XCosumer interfaces too.

Comment: EDIT: I made ArrayCaller generic so you can type it and you don't need to typecast the lambda anymore.

Comment: @TagirValeev to make it faster you can cache the reflection too, saving Method objects indexed by interface type (like TriConsumer).

Comment: With some wrapping and renaming it allows to write in this manner: `Stream.of(...).forEach(e -> retrieve(e::getName, e::getAge, e::getSalary)
        .thenCall(this::someOperationWithEmployee));` 
In comparison with the current: 
`Stream.of(..).forEach(e -> someOperationWithEmployee(e.getName, e.getAge(), e.getSalary));`

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no, you cannot do this. The shortest solution I can think up is to define your own functional interface like this:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface TriFunction<A,B,C,R> {
    R apply(A a, B b, C c);

    static <I,A,B,C,R> Function<I,R> convert(TriFunction<A,B,C,R> triFn, Function<I,A> aFn, 
                                             Function<I,B> bFn, Function<I,C> cFn) {
        return i -> triFn.apply(aFn.apply(i), bFn.apply(i), cFn.apply(i));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Stream.of(new Employee("Adam", 38, 3000), new Employee("John", 19, 2000))
    // some conversations go here
    .forEach(TriFunction.convert((a, b, c) -> someOperationWithEmployee(a, b, c), 
         Employee::getName, Employee::getAge, Employee::getSalary));
```

Though it's far from being beautiful.

I think it would be much better if your `someOperationWithEmployee` took the `Employee` object as an argument.

**Update**: for the *pair* of values you may use my free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library like this:

```
StreamEx.of(new Employee("Adam", 38, 3000), new Employee("John", 19, 2000))
    // some conversations go here
    .mapToEntry(Employee::getName, Employee::getAge)
    .forKeyValue((a, b) -> someOperationWithEmployee(a, b));
```

However it's limited to pairs only, so you cannot handle three or more values in this way (and I'm not going to add such functions).

I also checked the [jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) library as it's concentrated on tuples and already provides interfaces like [`Function3`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jooq/lambda/function/Function3.java). However it seems that there's no easy way to use it for your problem either.

Comment: Yes, I know about javaslang, but seems that it cannot help here either.

Comment: @Tagir It seems for me that jOOL is to broad and heavy solution in case of only Function3-FunctionN implementations. Maybe there some tiny libraries for this special and popular case (I mean functions with multiple arguments)?

Comment: I guess it's better to create such interfaces by yourself for your project. It seems to me that currently there's no "de-facto standard" for such interfaces.

Comment: You can use `this::someOperationWithEmployee` which makes it a bit nicer.

Comment: @StuartMarks, sure, usually I write like this, but OP asked for lambda notation. And I wanted to explicitly show in answer how many parameters the `someOperationWithEmployee` method takes.

Comment: @TagirValeev Fair enough. OP mentioned both styles, though; the text had a method reference but the code examples had the lambda with parameters. I'm not actually quite sure what the OP wants though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is redesigned in its own way [user270349](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270349/user270349)'s answer without reflection. With static import it can be used like so:

```
Stream.of(new Employee("Adam", 38, 3000), new Employee("John", 19, 2000))
        .map(e -> retrieve(e::getName, e::getAge, e::getSalary))
        .forEach(c -> c.call(this::printNameAgeSalary));
```

or like so:

```
Stream.of(new Employee("Adam", 38, 3000), new Employee("John", 19, 2000))
        .forEach(e -> retrieve(e::getName, e::getAge).call(this::printNameAge));
```

Here is code:

```
private void printNameAgeSalary(String name, int age, double salary) {
    System.out.format("%s %d %.0f\n", name, age, salary);
}

private void printNameAge(String name, int age) {
    System.out.format("%s %d\n", name, age);
}

public interface Consumer2<T1, T2> {
    void consume(T1 t1, T2 t2);
}

public interface Consumer3<T1, T2, T3> {
    void consume(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3);
}

public interface Caller<E> {

    void call(E code);

    static <S1, S2, S3> Caller<Consumer3<S1, S2, S3>> retrieve(Supplier<S1> s1, Supplier<S2> s2, Supplier<S3> s3) {
        return (Consumer3<S1, S2, S3> code) -> code.consume(s1.get(), s2.get(), s3.get());
    }

    static <S1, S2> Caller<Consumer2<S1, S2>> retrieve(Supplier<S1> s1, Supplier<S2> s2) {
        return (Consumer2<S1, S2> code) -> code.consume(s1.get(), s2.get());
    }
}
```